# Build is not get reflected in iTunes from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, testflight

I am trying to run ipa files on someones iPhone and I don't have access to the device. He is installing easily but when he tries to open the app then it goes blank. It may be because of permission which he needs to give, but he is not able to see the option of profile in settings. I installed on my iPhone with the help of “diawi” site very easily, which provides one link to install.

I am trying to use testflight now. Before using it I have to upload a build from archives in appStore(option in organiser of upload to appStore). Sometimes I upload it successfully but cannot see the build in iTunes. Bundle identifier is the same at both places and I think all certificates are also ok. Sometimes it also gives error like “ERROR ITMS-90534: Invalid Toolchain”. And some other errors sometimes. Thanks for reading this question.

Comment: use Application Loader once , wait for 30 min

Comment: thanks Shobhakar, I am getting some problem in installing AppLoader. I will try after it get installed. Do you have any more info about ERROR ITMS-90534?

Comment: are you using beta version of os or Xcode

Comment: This is my xcode:- Version 7.3.1 (7D1012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1012). When I upgraded my xcode to Version 8.0 (8A218a), then I am able to upload successfully. And yes, use applicationLoader.
In order to upgrade Xcode to 8.0 u need OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 atleast.